# WPF: Space in TextBox between border and text

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox with Width equals the width of a letter 'A'. But the letter is not displayed correctly.

Is it possible to avoid space between a border and the beginning of 'A'? `Padding="0"` does not help.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

Comment: Try `Padding="-5,0"` or whatever value is suitable

Comment: This seems strange to me. How I can sure that a chosen value will work correctly in all conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inspect visual tree with a tool like Snoop you can see that `TextBox` consists of `Border` that contains `ScrollViewer` that among others have `ScrollContentPresenter` that renders actual content of the `TextBox` with `TextBoxView` (1) internal class handling the rendering of content in the textbox and by default left and right margin set to "2" (2).
I don't think you can style the `TextBoxView` itself to override default margin values but as it is internally set to "2" you can safely assume that setting Padding on Textbox to "-2,0" will be fine.

Edit:

In [TextBoxView documentation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Documents/TextBoxView.cs)
you can find that in `TextBoxView` constructor (line 38) there is Margin property set to the constant value of `BidiCaretIndicatorWidth` (line 1219):
So probably it make sense to leave some space at the end and the beginning of the TextBox so the caret can be visible

```
static TextBoxView()
{
// Set a margin so that the bidi caret has room to render at the B edges of content.
   MarginProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBoxView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(CaretElement.BidiCaretIndicatorWidth, 0, CaretElement.BidiCaretIndicatorWidth, 0)));
}

(...)
// BiDi caret indicator width.
internal const double BidiCaretIndicatorWidth = 2.0;
```

[image]